# Canonical instead of canonicalized in the index - is it a rule?

Tags: seo, google, canonical-url

I experienced in some cases, that if one page is canonicalized to the another one, then, if i search for the canonicalized page in Google, in SERP appears the canonical page, and canonicalized page is doesn't displayed at all, or is hidden in supplemental results.

My question: is this behavior of Google a rule? Or does somebody experiences cases, where canonicalized page appears in SERP like without any canonicalization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a canonical tag is used, you are saying that the page specified in the canonical tag is preferred. So if one page's canonical tag points to another page, only the preferred page is shown in the search index. This is by design. Google will only show the preferred page in the SERPs.

Any exception to the rule is only temporary as Google processes what it finds.

As for Bing or any other search engine, I have no experience to comment.

Answer (score 1):

A canonical is one of the signals that Google uses to decides which page to index and show on the SERPs; because of that, they can decide to ignore it if the other signals point to another page that appears to be a better match.

The signals they use for this:

- Link rel canonical annotation that matches throughout the site
- Redirects
- Internal linking using the preferred URL format
- Preferred URLs in the sitemap file

*[Source](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-john-mueller-explains-how-canonical-urls-are-chosen/324371/)*

Comment: Posting the same answer to two questions here usually isn't a good idea.  Moderators automatically get notified when it happens and we have to take a look (which makes us grumpy.)   When the same answer applies it is usually (but not always) a sign that the questions are the same and one should be closed as a duplicate.   I think that is the case here.  It would be better to flag the question to be closed as a duplicate.  Once you have 3000 reputation, you will be able to vote to close questions directly yourself.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for letting me know!